# Can you have 2 views with separate exposed filters on 1 page?

Tags: drupal, view

I have two views loaded on the front page. Both contain exposed filters which when modified, display different content (done using the Better Exposed Filters module).

When modifying one view the URL will be http:example.com/?cid[]=1 and the changes will take effect.

When modifying the other view the URL will be http:example.com/?type[]=marketing_item and the changes will take effect however, this will reset the first view (this problem also happens when reversing the process).

Am I missing something or is this type of functionality not possible?

Answer (score 0):

Process $_GET['cid'] or $_GET['marketing_item'] in argument handling code of your views...